# debo crar una funcion que reciba como parametro el objeto perro y lo convierta en un array

Tags: javascript

**realizar una función que reciba como parametros el objeto perro y lo convierta en array
con la información del nombre, años y propietario del animal**
el arreglo debe retornar un mensaje de esta manera **'El perro se llama [nombre perro] y tiene [cantidad] años y su dueño es [dueño]'**

este es el parámetro

```
const perros = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Boby",
    edad: 2,
    propietario: "marcela",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "tom",
    edad: 8,
    propietario: "armando",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nombre: "princesa",
    edad: 2,
    propietario: "betty",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Toby",
    edad: 2,
    propietario: "mario",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    nombre: "Pepe",
    edad: 4,
    propietario: "freddy",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    nombre: "zulema",
    edad: 2,
    propietario: "willson",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    nombre: "peter",
    edad: 1,
    propietario: "steven",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    nombre: "sultan",
    edad: 3,
    propietario: "miguel",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    nombre: "nirvana",
    edad: 4, 
    propietario: "erick",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    nombre: "tormenta",
    edad: 8,
    propietario: "luis",
  },
];
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Tienes algún error?

Comment: Como ya mencionaron, no te vamos a hacer la tarea completa sin que tu lo hayas intentado antes. Dicho esto, de todas formas te dejo [aquí una pista de por donde empezar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

```
 const animal = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Hugo",
      edad: 2,
      propietario: "Josue",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "tom",
      edad: 8,
      propietario: "armando",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nombre: "Oliver",
      edad: 2,
      propietario: "Maykel",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      nombre: "Toby",
      edad: 2,
      propietario: "Andres",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nombre: "chachito",
      edad: 30,
      propietario: "Josue"
    }
  ];
```

```
const propietarioDeAnimales = () => {
      const propietariosDeAnimales = []
      for( let i =0;i < animal.length; i++){
          propietariosDeAnimales.push("el perro se llama "+animal[i].nombre+ " tiene una edad "+animal[i].edad + " y su dueño es " + animal[i].propietario  )
      }

      console.log(propietariosDeAnimales(animal))
  }
propietarioDeAnimales(animal)
```